# Script not running as cronjob

Tags: linux, debian, cron, perl

I got a script which runs in a cronjob as root.
The problem is that the addgroup command would output "Command not found" when it gets executed by the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$datei = `ls /var/www/cron/`;
@datei = split(/\n/, $datei);

foreach ( @datei ) {
    $datei = $_;
    open(bfh,"</var/www/cron/$datei") or die $!;
    while ( <bfh> ) {
        chomp($_);
        print "$_\n";
        system("$_\n");
    }
    #unlink("/var/www/cron/$datei") or die $!;
}
```

Crontab

```
  * * * * * /usr/bin/perl /home/hermes/cron.pl >> /home/hermes/cronlog
  2>> /home/hermes/cronerr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use absolute paths. Cronjobs run in a very minimal environment. The PATH variable may not contain what you expect.

Other than that: Set up sudo. Your current approach is hardly ideal.

Comment: I'm already using absolute paths in the crontab.
I would like to use sudo, but it isnt preinstalled in Debian and i'm not allowed to install it.

Comment: I’m of course referring to your „sub-jobs“ that are collected from `/var/www/cron/*`. Perl has [its own logic](http://perlmeme.org/faqs/file_io/directory_listing.html) for that, by the way.

Comment: I've copied the content of the PATH variable into the script. The problem is that is now outputting nothing.

Comment: You’re not checking the return value of `system()`. You’re also not doing what I told you: Put the absolute path(s) in your “job files”! Other than that, I must, again, really advise against this approach. Please talk to your superior or whatever.